# Differences in Seaborn's scatterplot and lmplot parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Some quick load ins:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

di = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

Using the example iris data set here. Create a scatterplot easily as follows:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=di['sepal_length'], y=di['sepal_width'], 
            hue=di['species']);
```

[image]

However  with lmplot a TypeError is raised and requires the data argument. With the data argument fulfilled, it still does not work:

```
sns.lmplot(x=di['sepal_length'], y=di['sepal_width'], 
            hue=di['species'], data=di);

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

However, this works just fine:

```
sns.lmplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species', data=di);
```

[image]

After reading the [API reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html), I see that lmplot requires the data argument, but scatterplot does not. Is there something different going on under the hood here? Also what are the best practices for the syntax here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is misuse of the `data` argument. Where `data` is passed, `x`, `y` and `hue` will be treated as objects with which to index the object passed in `data`, using its `__getitem__` method. So, for example, `x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', data=di` is equivalent to `x=di['sepal_length'], y=di['sepal_width']`

Accordingly, this runs:

```
sns.lmplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species', data=di);
```

What you tried to do was basically equivalent to `x=di[di['sepal_length']], y=di[di['sepal_width']], hue=di[di['species']]`.

Going back to the second part of your question regarding the difference between `scatterplot` and `lmplot`:

`scatterplot` is an `Axes`-level function; it relies only on `matplotlib`'s `Axes` object, which, when plotting, can work with such varied collection types as `lists` and `np.ndarrays`. Functionally, more or less, it is the same as `pyplot.scatter` with some default fancy colours.

On the other hand, `lmplot` relies on `sns.FacetGrid` (documentation available [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)). `FacetGrid` is a purely `sns` object that requires a `pd.DataFrame` when constructed. Accordingly, therefore, for `lmplot` to work, it *must* take a `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: Thank you. So if I am predominantly only working with pandas dataframes when making visualizations, should I really only be using sns.FacetGrid and other functions built on top of it? Or does it not really matter, and just use whatever is more convenient.

Comment: The other way round, I think; if you're only working with `pandas`, then it doesn't matter. On the other hand, if you work with data at a lower level of abstraction that's stored in `lists` or `arrays`, *then* which plots/libraries to use becomes a consideration.